# What does this pic rebus mean?

Tags: rebus

[image]

This is a simple rebus. What is this pic rebus saying?

Comment: 'it is better not to describe people with less PSE rep as "poor"' - [from Gareth, Puzzling moderator](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7330/69582)

Comment: What is even the point of putting a bounty on a question that was asked and answered years ago? Shouldn’t this be discouraged?

Comment: @SQLnoob i am super rich... points give away for poor people

Comment: Please stop referring to other people as "poor".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Things are getting out of hand.

Comment: From a syntactical and admittedly semantic point of view this would read rot13("'Guvatf' *vf* trggvat bhg bs unaq.")

Comment: Yes, but this is a rebus, they're usually not supposed to be taken that literally.

Answer (score 6):

While I feel @S. M.'s answer is the best depiction I could think of currently, the bounty suggests this is not the desired answer... It would be nice to get a solid response to their answer though.

Until then, I guess I'll try a couple of ideas as well:

> Losing my grip on things

or

> Things are growing out of hand

or

> Things are getting out of control

or

> Letting go of things

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw in my guess

> Letting things get out of hand

Which

> uses the full word "things" in a syntactically and semantically correct way (I think)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas...

If "What does this rebus say about life?", then

> A double-meaning for "The best things in life are free."

If "Who does this rebus say is the boss?", then

> I run things around here.

If "What famous book does this rebus represent?", then

> [Things Fall Apart](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Things-Fall-Apart)
>  ~ novel by Chinua Achebe

If "Should I say something, or not?", then

> Some things are better left unsaid. ("Things" are literally going away from one's consciousness.)

If "Should I act on these desires?", then

> Some things are best left to memories.
>  ~ Bez

If, "How can I ever achieve great things?", then

> Great things are done by a series of small things brought together. ("Things" assembling themselves in one's hand.)
>  ~ Vincent Van Gogh

I think I could go on all day with this, but I won't.